# Navigating the AOSP native code

Tags: android

Digging into some Android code brought me here:

[`android.hardware.input.InputManager.injectInputEvent()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/hardware/input/InputManager.java#608)

This uses IPC, here's the interface definition:

[`IInputManager.aidl`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/hardware/input/IInputManager.aidl)

How do I find the C++ implementation of the input manager?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [android.hardware.input.IInputManager](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/hardware/input/IInputManager.java?av=f). The abstract class `Stub` implements `android.hardware.input.IInputManager`. The concrete implementation of this stub in Java is in the [com.android.server.input.InputManagerService](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/com/android/server/input/InputManagerService.java?av=f) file. This class wraps the C++ InputManager.

Hope that helps you. Or are you looking for the C++ implementation?

[Here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/kitkat-release/services/input/) you find the C++ sources of all input services.

Please notice from the [InputManager.h](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/kitkat-release/services/input/InputManager.h) file:

> The InputManager class never makes any calls into Java itself.  Instead, the
>    InputDispatchPolicy is responsible for performing all external interactions with the
>    system, including calling DVM services.

Comment: The Stub is a Binder and uses IPC to call into native code. I'm looking for that native code.

Comment: I edited my post. However you should improve your question instead of just downvote.